# codeigniter login with twitter oauthclient library

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter

I'm using [oauthclient](https://github.com/jeroenmoors/oauthclient/downloads) to add a twitter login to my codeigniter project but it stops working at the "connect" function at "Oauthclient" library and I don't know exactly why !
here's the line where interpreter stops at :

```
                $oauth = new OAuth($this->consumerKey, $this->consumerSecret);
```

and here's the "connect" function :

```
 function connect() {

    if ($this->_oAuthVersion == 1) {

        try {

            $oauth = new OAuth($this->consumerKey, $this->consumerSecret);

            $request_token_info = $oauth->getRequestToken($this->_oAuthRequestTokenUrl, $this->responseUrl);
            if(!empty($request_token_info)) {
                $this->ci->session->set_userdata("oauth_token_secret", $request_token_info['oauth_token_secret']);
                header("Location: ".$this->_oAuthRedirectUrl.$request_token_info['oauth_token']);
            } else {
                print "Failed fetching request token, response was: " . $oauth->getLastResponse();
            }
        } catch(OAuthException $E) {
            // TODO: Handle exceptions in a better way
            // print_r($E);
            // echo "Response (RequestToken): ". $E->lastResponse . "\n";
        }
    } else {
        // If oAuth v2, we must be sure the url's are correctly poppulated
        // therefor, set the service type again
        $this->setService($this->serviceType);
        header("Location: ".$this->_oAuthRedirectUrl);
    }
}
```

I need your help , please.

Comment: Did you included / loaded the Oauth class?

Comment: do you mean "Oauthloader" class ?